# How to acquire copyright for Digimon franchise?

Tags: copyright, trademark

I'm not sure if this is the correct exchange to ask but hopefully it is.

Now if I want to acquire **Digimon** franchise **copyright** (Correct the term for me if I'm mistaken) for example for my Smartphone apps or Art.

Now what I know is if I want to make iMessage Sticker app on iOS for Digimon for example, I can get an artist who can draw the Digimons, but if I uploaded that app on App Store with Digimon name will be rejected without copyrights.

So I searched for who own **Digimon Franchise** on the web and actually it was a bit complex, I found that **Bandai** has the right to create Games, **Toei** animations has the right to create Anime, and I found also that **Saban Brands** bought Digimon Franchise a while ago, then **Walt Disney** acquired Saban Brands.

- Who is the responsible for a request like mine, So I can contact them ?
- Can any developer ask for their permission for copyrights ?

Correct me if any info provided is wrong or outdated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A matter of terminology, what you want is not the copyright, but a **license** to use the copyright, presumably a non-exclusive license.

You would probably need to approach a licensing department at Disney. They will ask lots of questions, and if they are open to the possibility, will quote a fee, which will, i would think, be sizable.

Anyone should be able to ask,  but I suspect that most requests are refused. It would probably be well to have a business plan laid out, and exactly how the images would be used in your plan.

Disney can refuse any license, or offer one on whatever terms it pleases.

Comment: Thanks for clearing out the correct terminology